# Avoid duplicate entries in room Database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, dao

I am trying to make a function which will check whether this id is already present or not in the database, But it is not working as required.It take the insert value in database.

```
private fun CheckDuplicateId(id:String,donorDao:DonorDao):Boolean{
        var result=true
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            donorDao.fetchAllDonor().collect(){
                var Donorlist=ArrayList(it)
                for(item in Donorlist){
                    if (item.id==id){
                        result=false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

I am using this function in while inserting the entry

```
private fun addRecord(donorDao:DonorDao){
        val Id:String=binding?.etDonorId?.text.toString()
        val bloodGr=binding?.etDonorBloodgroup?.text.toString()
        if(Id.isNotEmpty() && bloodGr.isNotEmpty() && CheckDuplicateId(Id,donorDao)){
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                donorDao.insert(DonorEntity(id = binding?.etDonorId?.text.toString(), bloodGroup = bloodGr))
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Record saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"duplicate value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

here donor entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "donor-table")
data class DonorEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var sr_no:Int=0,
    var id:String="",
    var bloodGroup:String="")
```

here donor dao

```
@Dao
interface DonorDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(donorEntity:DonorEntity)
    @Update
    suspend fun update(donorEntity:DonorEntity)
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(donorEntity:DonorEntity)
    @Query("SELECT*FROM `donor-table`")
    fun fetchAllDonor(): Flow<List<DonorEntity>>
    @Query("SELECT*FROM `donor-table` Where id=:id")
    fun fetchDonorById(id:Int): Flow<DonorEntity>
}
```

here the database

```
@Database(entities = [DonorEntity::class], version = 2)
abstract class DonorDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun donorDao():DonorDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE:DonorDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context):DonorDatabase{
            synchronized(this){
                var instance=INSTANCE
                if (instance==null){
                    instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        DonorDatabase::class.java,"donor_database")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                }
                INSTANCE=instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method returning true immediately:

```
private fun CheckDuplicateId(id:String,donorDao:DonorDao):Boolean{
    var result=true
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        donorDao.fetchAllDonor().collect(){
            var Donorlist=ArrayList(it)
            for(item in Donorlist){
                if (item.id==id){
                    result=false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result // return true immediately
}
```

So, do it inside

```
private fun addRecord(donorDao:DonorDao){
    val Id:String=binding?.etDonorId?.text.toString()
    val bloodGr=binding?.etDonorBloodgroup?.text.toString()
    if(Id.isNotEmpty() && bloodGr.isNotEmpty()){
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            // check here CheckDuplicateId(Id,donorDao) synchronously

            donorDao.insert(DonorEntity(id = binding?.etDonorId?.text.toString(), bloodGroup = bloodGr))
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Record saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"duplicate value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is at DB level is using index. This will only insert if table as no with same id value. You can avoid select * query which would affect performance if you have many data in you case.

```
@Entity(tableName = "donor-table",indices = [Index(value = ["id"], unique = true)])
data class DonorEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var sr_no:Int=0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id:String="",
    var bloodGroup:String="")
```

Comment: I want to show a toast to user when I add duplicate entry so how can I do that in this code?

Answer (score 0):

change the method to the below method because in your method, the result always returns true

```
private fun CheckDuplicateId(id:String,donorDao:DonorDao):Boolean{
        var result=true
        var  Donorlist = donorDao.fetchAllDonor()
                
                for(item in Donorlist.indices){
                    if (item[i].id==id){
                        result=false
                         break
                    }
                }
            }
        
        return result
    }
```